# Logic Apps Liquid transformation - how to test?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

Does anyone know if there is an editor or environment where you can test a Liquid template without uploading it to the IntegrationAccount and test it in the actual Logic App?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  Unfortunately, the tooling around Liquid Transform is...what tooling? :)

The LogicApp team really needs to include a Liquid Assembly in the next SDK.